# Absolute position elements so they behave like they are floated

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to make all these boxes behave like they are floated. However, they can’t be, they need to be absolutely positioned in order for me to interact with this positioned number.

Here's my attempt:

```
var $item = $('#wrapper div'),
    len = $item.length,
    itemWidth = $item.innerWidth(),
    winWidth = $('#wrapper').innerWidth(),
    cols = Math.floor(winWidth / itemWidth),
    moveX = itemWidth + 10;

function absPos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        $('.item-' + i).css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : moveX * i
        });
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out how to wrap them to fit, and also re-position when the window is resized.

Here’s a demo. http://jsfiddle.net/Fgcqs/3/ . If you un-commment the absPos() function you will see my start.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your jsfiddle to move the items like they are floated.  It assumes your margins and widths are the same for each of the divs within wrapper and will automatically work out the width and height of the spacing if your css changes

```
var wrapper =  $('#wrapper'),
    items = wrapper.children('div'),
    len = items.length,
    itemWidth = items.innerWidth() + parseInt(items.css('margin-left')) + parseInt(items.css('margin-right')),
    itemHeight = items.innerHeight() + parseInt(items.css('margin-top')) + parseInt(items.css('margin-bottom'));

items.css('float', 'none');


function absPos() {
    var cols = Math.floor(wrapper.width() / itemWidth);
    items.each(function() {

        var left = ($(this).index() % cols) * itemWidth; //the bit in brackets calculates which column the div should be in (the remainder of the current index of your item divided by the number of columns per row), then you times that by item width as worked out above, you use the index as this will allow you to start at left:0

        var height = Math.floor($(this).index() / cols) * itemHeight //the bit in brackets calculates which row the div should be in, then you times that by item height as worked out above, you use the Math.floor as this will allow you to start at top:0.  Should have really called this top!

        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'absolute', 
            'top': height,
            'left': left
        });
    });

    wrapper.height((Math.ceil(len / cols)) * itemHeight);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    absPos();
});
absPos();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgcqs/12/

Comment: Absolute legend! Would you mind explaining what the left and height vars are doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of both `column index` and `row index`: once `column index * item width` exceeds `window width`, reset `column index` and increment `row index` to simulate next row. Here's simple example of this approach:

```
function absPos() {
    var colIndex = 0;
    var rowIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        if (moveX * colIndex + itemWidth > winWidth) {
            colIndex = 0;
            rowIndex++;
            top += itemHeight + 10;
        }
        var left = moveX * colIndex; 
        var top = moveY * rowIndex;
        $('.item-' + i).css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : left,
            'top' : top
        });
        colIndex++;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N4S4L/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your *left* value plus the width of an item exceeds the width of your container, in which case introduce a *top* value and reset *left* to 0 to start building a new row.